# AS3 - Shutter animation

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

How to create a camera shutter animation (Example: [shutter .gif animation](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-QUzB8g8y0tQ/TazX2iGajqI/AAAAAAAAAQ8/pP7ViFVycY8/s1600/fotoartgif.gif)) and how to make it work for different screen resolutions?

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is not the shutter, but the diaphgram. Building and animating it like a real one works should be pretty easy;

Essentially there is a set of triangles attached to the frame at one of their corners, and are then rotated inwards to decide the aperture size.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_(optics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_%28optics%29)

Edit: I made a simple flash file to demonstrate the effect. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/340238/share/aperture.fla

Edit 2:
For dynamic placement;

```
dummy.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
dummy.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
var stageSize:int = (stage.stageWidth > stage.stageHeight ? stage.stageWidth : stage.stageHeight);
displacement = stageSize * K + M;  //Where K and M are constants that you might have to experiment a bit to get. My guess is K = 1, M = 100
```

You would also have to increase the size of the triangles to match.

Comment: Can be an old type of shutter, or the shutter of a 4*5 inches camera (where shutters are located in the lens).
See (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_shutter#Diaphragm_shutter)
But you're right actually since the most cameras use curtains based shutters. So most of people will consider this as a diaphragm animation NOT a shutter!
The sample is clear and easy to understand for everybody.
Well done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. One thing I don't understand is how to make it cover the whole stage. (When the aperture closed the whole stage is filled by it)

Comment: If you experiment with the dummy (center point), the distance (how far away from the center point the blade is placed) and the number of blades, you should be able to find a suitable value. If you need to do it on the fly, you should be able to multiply the larger of stageWidth and stageHeight by some value (and possibly with an offset) and set that as distance to get a nice fit. See update.